# Make only 1 instance of a character allowed to be entered C#

Tags: c#

I would like to allow only one instance of a character to appear in sequence in a textbox. In other words, I would like to prevent the user from entering sequential duplicate characters in my textbox. For example, if I were to make a calculator program, I would like to prevent the user from entering `((` by accident instead of `(`.

Comment: interesting question, I look forward to the answers - can't immediately think of an elegant solution.

Comment: @VSO please clarify what you think this question is about, also consider clarifying relation between textbox and array split.

Comment: A calculation tool, doing 5++5 doesn't make sense, 5+5 does

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: I think it should sound something like this: "I would like to allow only one instance of a character to appear in sequence in a textbox. In other words, I would like to prevent the user from entering sequential duplicate characters in my textbox. For example, if I were to make a calculator program, I would like to prevent the user from entering '((' by accident.  " I am not going to edit the post because there are a lot of caveats and ways to go about it and I don't want to put words in the poster's mouth.

Comment: @VSO I see - makes sense now. Along with OP comment about writing calculator... Also something like `((3+55)*4 + 5) *11` is quite a valid expression to compute - probably OP does not actually build calculator so.

Comment: @Jeremy11232: Can you elaborate on that, the string will only have two characters? It's important. As of right now - my solution would be to listen for change in the texbox. Any time a change is made, check if the last character is a duplicate of the second last - you can do this by checking the string length and then selecting the last and second to last characters. If they match, do nothing, if they don't, update the textbox. I don't work with windows forms, so I can't tell you exactly how it handles keydown. I am only posting to narrow down your goals. People can answer better that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect the textbox's keydown event. And in the event, you check the last and second last character to see if it's the same. If it's the same, you can just remove the last character of the string.

But keep in mind that the above method has problem when your user pastes the entire string to the textbox.

Comment: That is very close to what I want, but yeah it would be nicer to detect duplicates of certain values without it being the last character entered

Comment: Split the string into individual characters. Define an empty array uniqueChars. Define an array singleOnly. Run a foreach loop on every character in the string. In the loop, check if the character is already in the unique chars array, if not, check if it's in the singleOnly array. If both conditions are met, add to it to the uniqueChars array. When you encounter a duplicate (already in uniqueChars array, in your definition of characters you check for dupes), delete it. Then recombine the string and use it. Very inefficient, but will do it. Edit: Actually lists are probably better here.

Answer (score 0):

The function will look the same for any textbox-like object, but of course the event to attach to will differ. Assuming Winforms TextBox, you will attach to the TextChanged event (i.e. mytextbox.TextChanged = mytextbox_TextChanged), and the function will look similar to the one below:

```
private void mytextbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (mytextbox.Text.Length < 2)  { return; }

    var stringToCheck = mytextbox.Text;
    for (var i = 1; i <= stringToCheck.Length-1; i += 1)
    {
        if (stringToCheck[i].Equals(stringToCheck[i-1])
        {
            mytextbox.Text = stringToCheck.Remove(i, 1);

            // Next two lines put cursor at end of textbox instead of beginning
            mytextbox.SelectionStart = mytextbox.Text.Length;
            mytextbox.SelectionLength = 0;
        }
    } 

}
```